# How to get Google Maps 3 Directions Service API to distinguish multiple routes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) to get driving distances from multiple routes. Each route is being taken by a different driver; they all have the same start point but different endpoints and might have multiple waypoints.

The problem I'm having is that the API doesn't seem to give me any way to name each route, so when they come back asynchronously, I can't be sure which route belongs to which driver. It's true that each route has different addresses, but the DirectionsService response object gives me back slightly different addresses than I send -- "Des Plaines, IL" becomes "Des Plaines, IL, USA", for instance -- making it unreliable to compare those.

The API doesn't seem to let me send arbitrary strings with the request object to name them uniquely. So what can I do?

A code snippet that *might* help clarify what I'm doing:

```
$.getJSON(ajaxsource, function(data) {
    var darr = data.driver_info, // includes driver name, start and end addresses
        driver, start, end,
        waypts = [];
    for (var i=0,j=darr.length; i<j; i++) {
        if (driver==$.trim(darr[i][8])) { // same driver, next destination
            //  start = end;
            waypts.push({
                location: end,
                stopover: true });
        } else {
            waypts = [];
            driver = $.trim(darr[i][8]);
            start = $.trim(darr[i][4]);
        }
        end = $.trim(darr[i][2]);

        if (i+1==j || driver!=$.trim(darr[i+1][8])) { 
            var request = { // route object
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                waypoints: waypts,
                optimizeWaypoints: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
                // console.log(response);
                for (var k=0; k<legs.length; k++) {
                    $('#results').append($('<li>').html("Driver " + driver + 
                        "<br>starts at " + legs[k].start_address + 
                        "<br>and drives " + legs[k].distance.text + 
                        "<br>to end at " + legs[k].end_address));
                }
            });
        };

    }; // end for
}); // end getJSON
```

That code will return all the route info as desired, but since it's asynchronous, the `driver` in each result is the name of the last driver listed in my `data.driver_info` array. What I need is to list the driver that should be associated with that particular route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more debugging uncovered a solution -- the Google documentation didn't mention that the `response` object doesn't just contain a status and routes, but also a sub-object called `ub` which mirrors the request object I sent. Using that, I can compare addresses exactly to match routes to drivers.

```
Object
    routes: Array[1]
    status: "OK"
    ub: Object
        destination: "1234 Some Street, Antioch, IL"
        optimizeWaypoints: true
        origin: "2345 Anywhere Ave., Lake Forest, IL"
        travelMode: "DRIVING"
        waypoints: Array[0]
        __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object
```

I added the following code inside my `directionsService.route()` callback:

```
var driver = '',
    end_ub = response.ub.destination;
for (var a=0,b=darr.length; a<b; a++) {
    if (darr[a][2]==end_ub) {
        driver = darr[a][8];
        break;
    };
};
```

Comment: Hi @Blazemonger seems like response sub-object `ub` is no more available. I have the same scenario where i need some additional information on route legs, that i can pass in my way points. But i need to get that in my response. Any idea?

Comment: Never mind, i solved it by utilizing the `waypoint_order` object!

Answer (score 2):

Set a `var loc_driver = driver;` within the loop so that you can have it local to the `for` loop, and then use that value in your callback rather than relying on the "global" (at least, relative to the entire `getJSON` call) value.

The callback to the directionsService has within scope variables from the for loop and the entire `function(data){ ... }`.

The problem is that `driver` changes with each pass of the for-loop, and your callback uses that "global" `driver`.  If instead you set a variable that lives only within the scope of each for loop, and the callback relies on that variable, then problem solved.

EDIT: there may be some reference vs value issues, so how about declare somewhere convenient:

```
callbackFactory = function(driver) {
   return function(request, status) {
     var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
     console.log(response);
     for (var k=0; k<legs.length; k++) {
        $('#results').append($('<li>').html("Driver " + driver +
             "<br>starts at " + legs[k].start_address + 
             "<br>and drives " + legs[k].distance.text + 
             "<br>to end at " + legs[k].end_address));
     }
   };
};
```

and then in your control structure:

```
directionsService.route(request, callbackFactory(driver));
```

Comment: Please clarify. My problem is that AFAIK, I can't pass arbitrary variables to the Google directionsService callback.

Comment: That's true, but: you can pass arbitrary callbacks, and those callbacks have access to variables that are in scope when they (the callbacks) are declared.  Which is sort of like being able to pass them arbitrary variables.  My point is: you're already using one variable based on scope (driver), just pick a different variable with the correct scope (each loop pass).

Comment: Sorry, but that solution does not work. The callback passed to `directionsService.route()` doesn't take `loc_driver` with it, and I still get the same driver for all routes.

Comment: okay, I tried a different approach to getting the scope right.  I'll also point out: the call to `append` the content is also subject to some asynchrony issues.  Probably best to build the entire addition in the loop, then append in one step outside of it.

Comment: one additional comment: I threw together a demonstration of the principle involved in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m5uvw/

Comment: re: appending the content -- yep, I thought of that later. Solved it in a different manner, by building empty `<li>` tags with `id` equal to the driver's name (sans spaces), then appending content to the correct driver's `<li>` asynchronously. Won't detail it here since it's not really relevant to the original question.